# War "jemanden zu etwas vermögen" einmal verbreitet?

Tags: verb-usage

Ich entdeckte soeben bei Werner Bergengruen diese Formulierung. Hier ein Bild der Passage:

[image: Aus *Die Sultansrose* von Werner Bergengruen]

Ich wüsste nun sehr gern ob diese Verwendung des Verbs "vermögen" einmal üblich war. Falls wir zur Annahme neigten, dass sie nie weit verbreitet war, so würde mich interessieren, ob sie unter den Deutschen des Baltikums verbreitet war. Ein solcher war schließlich Bergengruen. Besonders interessiert bin ich, wie immer, an Passagen aus der Deutschen Literatur, welche etwa diese Verwendung belegten.

Selbstverständlich habe ich in neueren Ausgaben des *Duden* ohne Erfolg gesucht.

Comment: "Versichern" verwendet man so heutzutage auch nicht mehr.

Comment: @Em1 das ist für mich noch völlig normal, aber von der Tendenz her haben Sie Recht.

Comment: Ich schätze, hier fehlt einfach ein *zu bringen/veranlassen*. In Brockhaus und Meyer aus dem 19. Jahrhundert und bei Zeno.org habe ich zahlreiche *vermocht* gefunden, aber alle folgen entweder dem Muster *zu [Verb im Infinitiv] vermocht* (etwa 95%) oder  *so gut er es vermochte* (5%).

Comment: @guidot *jmd zu etwas vermögen* hieß damals ganz einfach *jmd zu etwas bringen/veranlassen*. Es fehlt nicht, wir verstehen es nur nicht mehr. Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: @tofro Die ersten Werke Bergengruens entstanden 80 Jahre nach Grimm, daher finde ich das Grimm-Argument nicht zwingend, zudem es zu dessen Zeit anscheinend schon veraltet war. Es könnte natürlich sein, dass Bergengruen den Sprachstil der erzählten Zeit nachempfunden hat, also bewusst historisierend formuliert hat. Das kann ich anhand des knappen Schnipsels ohne Quellenangabe aber nicht erkennen.

Comment: @guidot Hast du eine Begründung/einen Beleg für "veraltet zu Zeiten von Grimm"? Im Wörterbuch steht dazu nichts - Er sagt "Heute Akkusativ mit 'zu' ", was ja genau dem Bergengruen-Beispiel entspricht.

Comment: @tofro: Auch ein Standpunkt. Für mich heißt mit *zu*: mit Infinitiv und nicht *zu einer Zusammenkunft* auch den *heute [1840] meist ergänzt*en Satz finde ich nicht. Also fiele das Bergengruen-Beispiel für mich unter den persönlichen (Feind Ludwig) Akkusativ ohne weiteren Zusatz, also *aus älterer Zeit*. Hast du denn schon einen Beleg der Verwendung von *vermögen* im 20 Jahrhundert nach deiner Theorie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sucht man nach solchen früheren Bedeutungen, hilft oft  [das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch von 1840](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/). Das weiß zu "vermögen" in der zitierten Form:

> 2) trans., macht haben über etwas, in älterer zeit gern mit dem persönlichen accus. ohne weiteren zusatz. heute accus. meist durch satz mit zu ergänzt. in älterer zeit und mundartlich hat die construction mit absolutem accus. mancherlei bedeutungen: einen vermögen, einen in seiner gewalt haben, eines habhaft werden: welcher freund den andern vermag, der steckt jn in sack. Luther 5, 271; einer von seinen fürnehmen bedienten, der ihn wohl vermochte. pers. rosenth. 1, 21; der den andern vermag, der steckt denselben in sack.

Es scheint sich also um eine gebräuchliche Form des Verbs zu handeln, die nicht nur innerhalb regionaler Grenzen verwendet wurde.

Die Kurzfassung deines Beispielsatzes lautet meiner Ansicht nach allerdings (erleichtert um alle Ausschmückungen und Anhängsel):

> Er hat seinen Feind zu einer Zusammenkunft vermocht

im Sinne von "er hat ihn dazu bringen (oder auch zwingen) können". Mit einer "räumlichen Richtung", wie in deiner Überschrift vermutet, hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: Diese Antwort überzeugt mich sehr, obwohl das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch die möglichen Bedeutungen sehr im unklaren lässt. Gibt es davon eine online-Fassung?

Comment: @Ludi Ja, und das ist gut so: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/

Comment: Im Schwedischen haben wir immernoch diese zweite Bedeutung von vermögen ("förmå"), = jmd zu etwas bringen

Comment: Mittlerweile habe ich die Formulierung auch in Schopenhauers geschmackloser Schrift *Über die Weiber* gefunden. *Mit den Mädchen hat es die Natur auf Das, was man im dramaturgischen Sinne, einen Knalleffekt nennt, abgesehen, indem sie dieselben, auf wenige Jahre, mit überreichlicher Schönheit, Reiz und Fülle ausstattet, [...] damit sie [...] der Phantasie eines Mannes sich in dem Maße bemächtigen könnten, daß er hingerissen wird, die Sorge für sie [...] zu übernehmen; zu welchem Schritte ihn zu vermögen, die bloße vernünftige Ueberlegung keine hinlänglich sichere Bürgschaft zu geben schien.*